# How to addEvent in Qunit Checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, addeventlistener, qunit

I am working with QUnit and have one simple requirement that: I need my custom checkbox in the "qunit-testrunner-toolbar" where already there are 3 checkboxes.

I can add a checkbox using:

```
QUnit.config.urlConfig.push({
id: 'foo',
value: 'bar',
label: 'Enable foo',
tooltip: '...'
});
```

But how do I can addEvent to it. Suppose I want this checkbox to perform a simple function so that checking it will only show testcases with name "GoodTest" and hide all others.

Thanks in Advance !!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to write that functionality yourself. When you add checkboxes like this the id/value get placed in the query string when a user checks it. In other words, for your code above, when the checkbox is checked, the URL will change to: `http://localhost:80/my-test.html?foo=bar`

You need to write JavaScript code to read the query string and then do something based on values that are (or are not present) like so:

```
var params = document.location.search.substr(1).split('&');
for (var i=0; i<params.length; ++i) {
  if (params[i] === 'foo=bar') {
    // user has checked your box, do whatever you need to do!
  }
}
```